# I want to grep/extract some website immediately above a particular string

Tags: javascript, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want some specific websites to be extracted/grep before a string.

Example below:

Lets assume what is below is gibberish that i only want to extract website that is above `SOLUTION NEEDED` only! Not the other websites.

I only want to extract websites that can be found immediately above `SOLUTION NEEDED`

```
[36m[•] URL: abvfrt.com|LOAD
EXCEPTION: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
[36m[•] URL: abc dot com |LOAD: xyz=345
EXCEPTION: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
URL: Example dot com |: ABXCDRTTT
33m SOLUTION NEEDED
```

Comment: Is there anything you've tried yet?

Comment: Cannot assist, need sample input, and sample output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep -B n and -A n for showing you n number of lines **B**efore or **A**fter the matched string.

In your case, something like

`grep -B 1 "SOLUTION NEEDED" /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting try this:

```
  grep -B1 "SOLUTION NEEDED" long.log | grep -oP "(?<=^URL: )[^|]*"
```

### Explanations:

#### `grep -B1 "SOLUTION NEEDED" long.log`

Extract 1 line before each line matching `"SOLUTION NEEDED"`

#### `grep -oP "(?<=^URL: )[^|]*"`

From extracted lines. Extract URL value.